# XAMPP -- Apache Server won't start

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am in the XAMPP control panel with the Start buttons to Aoache and MySQL enabled. While clicking on the Start button to MySQL works fine, showing the available port, when I click on the Start button to Apache, I first get a message saying "Attempting to start Apache service" Then I get a popup window appears, asking if I want Net Command to make a change to my device. I initially clicked yes, but nothing happened.

I later saw these three red lines when I launched the XAMPP control panel:

```
2:36:34 PM  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
2:36:34 PM  [Apache]    Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
2:36:34 PM  [Apache]    Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

Now I used to have Apache2.4 installed prior to installing XAMPP, but I had completely uninstalled it before installing XAMPP. I see no trace of Apache2.4 remaining, nor do I see the folder that the above three lines referred to.

I'm trying to get the Apache server launched in XAMPP, so I can get started with PHP, but I don't know how to resolve this issue with the previous Apache2.4, which I'd already uninstalled, but somehow, there's some dangling reference to Apache2.4.

What do I need to do so that Apache on XAMPP launches correctly? Is there something I'm missing?

I tried uninstalling the old Apache2.4, expecting to see this in the list of apps to uninstall, but it's not there (from when I'd previously uninstalled Apache 2.4). Given that, I don't see why XAMPP seems to think there's a previous Apache server existing on my computer.

Comment: (1) make sure you have deleted the "C:\Apache24\ ..." folder and rebooted your PC (2) edit your windows path to remove any one related to c:\Apache24 (typing environment variable into your Windows Search bar and clicking “Edit the system environment variables.” then edit the path)

Answer (score 0):

Once you uninstall the Apache2.4 restart your device and then install XAMPP. It works to me, I hope it'll works to you.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 Install latest version of Xampp

STEP 2 Change port to 8080 and 4433

STEP 3 Delete WpnService

- Press Win + R from your keyboard, type regedit.exe into Run dialog box, and click OK button to open the registry editor.
- Double click on the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to expand the sub-folder, and navigate to the location below:

SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services

- Select the WpnService
- Go to the right side panel, find "Start" registry, right click and delete it.

STEP 4 Enjoy and start coding...